# Struct Scope Access

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scope

Hi this a continuation of a previous question I asked however I wasn't registered then and thus cannot edit the question. Anyways I have a struct

```
typedef struct
{
 char input[100][100];
 int count;
 char name;
 int startTime;
}INPUT;

extern INPUT *global;
```

this is within the header file. A stackoverflow member suggested that in my source file i use

```
INPUT global_[N], *global = global_;
```

to declare and initialise it which worked fine(as in I was able to store and print information out of the struct from within that method) however when I go to use the variable in other parts of my code it seems that the variable is out of scope?

I declare and use the variable global_ in a method called readFile and i'm trying to access the same information in main via *global.

Can this be done?
Thanks
Chee

Comment: Which variable are you referring to?

Comment: For the question to be answered, you need to specify where exactly `global` is defined. It might help when you link to the original question.

Comment: Are you trying to access `global_` or `global` from outside the file where they are defined? If so, you may want to use `extern` to declare them. Otherwise, please provide a minimal non-working example..

Comment: @Michael: Look again. It's `extern INPUT *global;`.

Comment: As I read it, I take it that Chee substituted that one for the suggestion that appears below it. Maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> extern INPUT *global;
> ```

This declares a global variable named `global`.

> ```
> INPUT global_[N], *global = global_;
> ```

This defines an array `global_` and a variable `global`. Depending on where this definition occurs (at function scope, or in a namespace, a class, or a function), `global` might or might not define the same object that's referred to by the declaration of `global`.